# Wireshark capturing only 802.11 beacon and probresponce only in ubuntu14.04

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

wireshark/tcpdump in Ubuntu, was capturing all 802.11 wifi packets ( beacon, probrequest, probresponse, association request/response and data packets). Now only beacon, prob response packets capturing. pls help, what is the problem for capturing other packets.

Comment: Maybe some filters?

Comment: I am not using any filters.